# Navbar split horizontally by color/image with linear gradient

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I'm trying to create a bootstrap navbar that has the top half in a certain color with 0.9 opacity and a background-image behind it, and the bottom half with complete transparency (opacity 0) just showing the body's color/background-image.

I've been playing for hours now with linear gradients trying to achieve the effect, but the closest I've got is...

```
html, body { 
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("/someBackgroundTexture.png");
}

.theNavBar {

  background-image: 

    linear-gradient(
     to bottom, 
     rgba(127, 180, 220, 0.9) 0%,  /*opacity 0.9*/
     rgba(127, 180, 220, 0.9) 50%, /*opacity 0.9*/
     rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, /*transparent*/
     rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100% /*transparent*/
   )  
   ,url("/someNavbarTexture.png");

   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}
```

It works well in terms of dividing the navbar into 2 pieces with different colors, but the problem is that "someNavbarTexture.png" is applied in the wrong half (the bottom half of the navbar), and is effectively just doing the same job that the background-image of html,body is.

What I want to do is somehow assign the ",url("/someNavbarTexture.png");" to the first 2 rows of the linear-gradient (which seems impossible).

Is there any easier way to achieve this effect with CSS? (I really don't care if I end up using linear-gradients or not!)  Thanks for any thoughts at all.

---

### --------EDIT---------

Here's a link explaining what I'm talking about...

http://codepen.io/d3wannabe/pen/gPPmOv

Comment: We'd really need to see this not working to be able to judge but it *sounds* as though you need to specify two different background positions.

Comment: Hi Paulie, just updated my post with a link to codepen showing the problem (including a comment at the bottom showing an example texture I want to apply to the top half of the container) - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can see of doing this is with a pseudo-element (or div if you wish) that is absolutely positioned and is 50% of the container height.

```css
/* Pen-specific styles */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
/* Pattern styles */

.container {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(127, 180, 220, 0.9) 0%, rgba(127, 180, 220, 0.9) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.container:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-image: url("http://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/3px-tile.png");
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  </div>
```